# Откуда лишняя строка при переборе массива? Как её убрать?

Tags: php, массивы, сессия

На главной странице с помощью Ajax добавляю в сессию товары, далее циклом их вывожу, но получается дополнительная строка, есть подозрение, что это 0 элемент массива, однако он не всегда получается в начале списка... Жду версий и решений проблемы!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
//js, если нужно
$(document).ready(function() {
    
 $(".good a").click(function(){

        var parent = $(this).parent() ;
        var count = parent.find('.string').val();
        var id = parent.find('.string').attr('id');
        var price = parent.find('.string').attr('price');
        var item_name = parent.find('.string').attr('item_name');
        var total_price = $('.totalprice').val();
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "page2.php",
         data: {good_id: id,
                count: count,
                price: price,
                item_name: item_name},
          success: function(data){alert(data+'Товар добавлен')}

        });
        

     
     return false;
 
    
});

        
  


});
```

```html
//не первой странице
<div class="good" >
        <input class="string" type="text" price="<?=$row['price']?>" id="good_<?=$row['id']?>" item_name="<?=$row['name']?>" >
        <a href="#">В корзину</a>
       </div>
 // на второй странице
 <?php



session_start();




$_SESSION['item_name'][$_POST['good_id']]=$_POST['item_name'];
$_SESSION['count'][$_POST['good_id']]=$_POST['count'];
$_SESSION['price'][$_POST['good_id']]=$_POST['price'];
//$_SESSION['total_price']=$_POST['total_price'];

?>
<div class="cart_layout" style="display:flex; justify-content:space-around;">


<div class="item_name" style="background-color:green;">
 <strong>НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ ТОВАРА:</strong><br>
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['item_name'] as $item_name){
 echo($item_name)."    <br>";
}
?>
</div>

<div class="count">
 <strong>КОЛЛИЧЕСТВО:</strong><br>
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['count'] as $count){
 echo $count." л.   <br>";
}
?>
</div>

<div class="total_count">
<strong>СУММА:</strong><br>

<?php
$z=array_map(function ($el1, $el2) {
  return $el1 * $el2;
},
$_SESSION['count'], $_SESSION['price']);
foreach ($z as $total) {
  echo $total."   <br>";
}
?>
</div>





</div>
```

Comment: А когда эта пустая строка вылетает? Вот вы добавляете добавляете и в какой-то момент ловите пустую строку? или как

Comment: Она вылетает всегда, не зависимо от того, добавил я товар или нет.

Comment: Ну тогда другое дело, и есть предположение, щас добавлю в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уровень кода конечно оставляет желать лучшего. Переходите на фреймворки :<

Если вы когда-то там ловите пустой массив, то думаю так вам подойдет:

**После** `//$_SESSION['total_price']=$_POST['total_price'];` вставьте:

```
foreach($_SESSION['item_name'] as $key => $value){
    if (empty($value)) {
        unset($_SESSION['item_name'][$key]);
        unset($_SESSION['count'][$key]);
        unset($_SESSION['price'][$key]);
    }
}
```

---

Скорее всего вы вторую страницу грузите сразу, а там у вас `$_POST['good_id']` пустой-жеж, отсюда и пустой элемент, можно тогда такой вариант:

После `session_start();`:

```
if (!isset($_POST['good_id']) AND !empty($_POST['good_id'])) {
    // Пустая таблица
} else {
    // Ваш код таблицы
}
```

Comment: Оставляет желать лучшего, потому что все намешано и сложно читается или по каким то другим причинам?

Comment: @orel-22 именно поэтому, все в куче, небезопасно, и несовременно.

Comment: Знаете, обычно вторую страницу загружаю уже после добавления товаров, и результат тот же, пустая строка в какой-то части таблицы... позже попробую оба варианта и отпишу вам тут.

Comment: @orel-22 ну тогда первый вариант вас спасет.

Comment: Первый вариант помог, спасибо!